# Quasipolynomial and polynomial time hierarchy

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Consider the following two scenarios:

1. $NP\subseteq RTIME[2^{(\log n)^c}]$ or $NP\subseteq DTIME[2^{(\log n)^c}]$, i.e., $NP$ can be solved in quasipolynomial randomized or deterministic time.
2. $NP$ has quasipolynomial size circuits.

Does the polynomial time hierarchy $PH$ collapse under any of the above conditions?

The first condition implies $EXP=NEXP$. Does the second imply the same or something weaker?

Could $P=BPP$ still hold in such situations?

---

Separately what implications follow from $EXP=NEXP$ and/or $EXP$ having quasipolynomial circuits?

Answer (score 5):

1. If $NP$ can be solved in quasipolynomial time, then $NP$ has quasi polynomial size circuit.
2. The second condition implies that the exponential time hierarchy collapses to the second level (as was shown in the [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-56287-7_99) of Buhrman and Homer). It was improved the collapse to $S_2^{exp}$ in a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397507004859) of Pavan et al.
3. As far as I know, these hypotheses do not easily imply a collapse of PH.

Answer (score 4):

By a translation argument, you can get that $QuasiNP \subseteq QuasiR/QuasiP$ and hence $PH \subseteq QuasiR/QuasiP$. I believe the second condition will imply a similar conclusion in terms of collapsing $PH$ to some level of "$QH$".

For the second part of your question, $EXP \subseteq p/poly \implies EXP = MA$. You can extend this result $EXP \subseteq p/quasi-poly \implies EXP = MATIME(Quasi)$.

Comment: NP=RP doesn't imply that PH collapses to RP, only to BPP. Why would the quasipolynomial case be different?

Comment: Also, the quasipolynomial version of MA is closed under quasipolynomial reductions, whareas EXP is not (by the time-hierarchy theorem). Thus, the two classes are distinct (unconditionally). Presumably you only meant an inclusion.

Comment: Oh, and "P/quasipoly" means "P with quasipolynomial advice". Since a P-machine has no time to read more than polynomially many bits of the advice anyway, this actually equals P/poly! The proper notation for the class of languages having circuits of size f(n) is SIZE(f(n)), but here QP/quasipoly would also do.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : ​ I don't see how that works, since the input can affect [which advice bits the machine reads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_Turing_machine). ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer P is normally defined using regular TM, not random-access TM. Even so, the notation is ambiguous at best.