# Permanent in Bounded error Quasi Poly time

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, big-picture, permanent, hierarchy-theorems

Is there any consequence to complexity theory if Permanent has a BQP (classical quasipoly version of BPP)?

Is there any consequence to complexity theory if Permanent has a QP (classical quasipoly version of P)?

I could not find any consequences from quick search on google (except for a result by Jin Cai on #P, EXP and BPTIME) and Valiant's original hypothesis only says VP is not VNP.

It could be that permanent has a quasipoly algorithm or circuit. Is there any arguments for and against this?

Comment: You would get a quasipoly algorithm for any problem in PH. Isn't that surprising enough?

Comment: @SashoNikolov what if even they are all in quasipoly it does not disturb the complexity landscape? It could still be P=BPP right?

Comment: A quasipoly algorithm for any problem in PH to me seems like a huge disturbance in the complexity landscape

Comment: @SashoNikolov sorry by disturbance I mean any violation to relative ordering of classes (like collapse results or P \neq BPP - any thing unexpected at all other than PH in Qpoly)?

Comment: See this answer http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/36764/4896

Comment: @SashoNikolov oh I see some other implication outside PH.