# What is consequence of $PH\subseteq NSPACE((\log n)^2)$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, space-complexity, logspace

What is consequences of $PH\subseteq NSPACE((\log n)^2)$?

We don't even know PH is equals to L or not. I am wondering what will be happened when $PH\subseteq NSPACE((\log n)^2)$?

Comment: For $NP \subseteq NSPACE((\log(n)^2)$, it contredicts the ETH, since it implies that all $NP$ problem can be solve in $n^{\log(n)}$ times. From https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/36750/quasipolynomial-and-polynomial-time-hierarchy you get that Exp-time hiearchy collapse at the second level.